# WinApi: How to resize the window region on MouseMove event correctly?

Tags: winapi, regions

My application is screenshot maker. User needs to select screen area to make a screenshot. I use Win32 API with PureBasic, but it doesn't matter, all is similar with C++. 
When user runs application, the semitransparent borderless form is shown on full screen to hook mouse over all other windows. On mouse down event selection is started and I apply XORed region to the form to cut a hole in it with size of current selection.

I create and apply a new region on every **mousemove** event:

```
rgn1 = CreateRectRgn_(0,0,DWidth,DHeight) ; full size of desktop
rgn2 = CreateRectRgn_(sx, sy, ex, ey) ; current selection points
CombineRgn_(rgn1, rgn1, rgn2, #RGN_XOR)
SetWindowRgn_(WindowID(0), rgn1, #True); apply region
```

It works well on my computer with Windows XP, but works buggy on other computer with Vista. I think it is wrong when I create the new region object on every mouse move. Maybe I need to create it once and then to resize? Can anybody explain how to do this right? Examples on C++ are ok.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning you create region, using **CreateRectRgn** (like in your code).
Then it's enough to call **SetRectRgn** function for updating region bounds